# This question is related to google spreadsheet number formating

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have a number "1,015,788" i want this number to be displayed as 10.15L. How can i do this in google spreadsheet?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To change the formatting of the number to what you've described, use the following formula.

```
=TEXT(TRUNC(1015788/100000,2),"#.##L")
```